# NOT NULL constraint failed: users_details.user_id

Tags: django, null, constraints

I've tried to add another details form that have address and birth date on my registration form page. Every time i tried to sign up i get the NOT NULL constraint failed error.

models.py

```
class Details(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        o_form = DetailsForm(request.POST)
        if r_form.is_valid and o_form.is_valid():
            r_form.save()
            o_form.save()
            username = r_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        r_form = UserRegisterForm()
        o_form = DetailsForm()

    context = {
        'r_form' : r_form,
        'o_form' : o_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email','password1', 'password2']

class DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address = forms.CharField()
    birth_date = forms.DateField()
    class Meta:
        model = Details
        fields = ['address', 'birth_date']
```

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8oWn.png)

Comment: Your `Details` object links to a user, but your details form doesn't include a user field, so calling `save()` on that fails to fill the user attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While extraneous details/profile "sidecar" models are not the best practice since pluggable user models came along, this particular problem is caused by the two models not being associated.

Try

```
if r_form.is_valid and o_form.is_valid():
    user = r_form.save()
    o_form.instance.user = user
    o_form.save()
```

Comment: Dude, thanks so much, it really worked. But i still dont get it where was the problem. Could u care to explain?

Comment: @markwalker's comment in your original post really explains the problem :)